# Django template object not showing

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So I've come across this weird thing. I can't pass data within the template unless it's within the forloop.

for example..
I can pretty much print a variable just within a for loop but something outside a forloop is not showing up.

```
{{listings.make}} <<<< This isn't printing


{% for listing in listings %}
   <p>{{listing.make}}</p> <<<< This is printing
{% endfor%}
```

```
def search(request):
    queryset_list = Vehicle.objects.all()

    context = {

        'listings': queryset_list
    }

    return render (request, 'mainapp/new_listing.html', context)
```

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=YEAR)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=50, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.make
```

Any idea what is going on actually. As you can see I m using a function-based view.

Thank you

Comment: {{ listings }}, this will print

Comment: This is printing the object which is fine exp <QuerySet [<Vehicle: BMW>, <Vehicle: BMW>]>

Comment: it will print the list of your instances, if you want it individually, you have to loop through the list. In templates that is the way to see it, or you can loop through in your views

Comment: make sure you have value in `make`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `listings` is a queryset_list and not a *single* Vehicle; so it doesn't have a `make` field.

If you want to access the fields of your model, you should have a **single** object. One way of achieving that is to iterate through the objects, as you mentioned. Another way to get a single object (only the *first* one from the list) is to use `{{ listings.first.make }}`.